# Method selector with parameters iOS

Tags: ios, parameters, selector

In my iOS app i have an UIImageView and when i click on it a method is called.

This is the method:

```
- (void)tapImagesLike:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer idOfTheImage:(NSInteger*) id_image{

    //here i want to use the passed value id_image
}
```

I'm not able to call it and get the parameter in input.

This is the code that calls the method when the UIImageView is clicked:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapImagesLike:idOfTheImage:x)];

        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;                                                                                                 

        likeImageImageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;                                                                                            

        [likeImageImageview setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];                                                                                            

        [likeImageImageview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

x is the NSInteger that i want to give in input to the method.

How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give every `imageView` a tag, and use that tag as its id. So you don't need to pass the parameter. And modify the code like this:

```
- (void)tapImagesLike:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    UIView *imageView = recognizer.view; //cast it to UIImageView if needed
    //use imageView.tag as the id
}
```

Comment: My imageViews already got a tag. The tag is another parameter that i have to use

Comment: OK, you can just use a variable to store the id, and retrieve the id from that variable when tap triggered

Comment: sorry, i didn't say that the imageView is created dynamically in a loop, and in every loop my variable x changes. So if a store the value in a variable, i'll have the value that it get in the last loop. Isn't there any solution to pass this parameter to the method?

Comment: I am a bit confused, so how many `imageViews` you got? And what does that `idOfTheImage` for?

Comment: I have multiple imageViews downloaded form the web. Initially they're ten but when the user wants, he can click on a button and download other images that will be shown on the screen (i made another loop). Every image view has a tag that help me to understand  in which row of the loop i am while the id (x value) is the id of the image, downloaded from the web, that i have to use to send urlRequest when user clicks on the imageView.

Comment: OK, I understand. But a gestureRecongnizer will only pass one parameter which is itself. So you have to store the id for all the images somewhere like in an array

Comment: Why not to use UITableView and method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"? You will get the cell which contains your image and the index you clicked.

Comment: i solved with some math. I passed in the tag value an arithmetic expression composed by the two number i need. Then in the method, with some operation, i get the distinct values of the two int. Thanks!